# Style Views without preprocess

Tags: views

I created basic custom - made layout in Drupal 7 by setting up ( layout.info html.tpl.php page.tpl.php style.css )

I have also created Views in order to filter some certain content (text and photo). Is there a way to theme the Views but without preprocess functions. So no coding in the template.php ? How to do that if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always assign custom CSS classes to each field and target them for styling. Template.php file should be used more for a data manipulation purpose anyway, rather than styling.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to theme the Views but without preprocess functions.

Views usually provides handy CSS classes and wrappers by default. You can configure them in the format and field settings.

In addition, you can also override the templates of views in the same way you override other parts of Drupal with templates. Under the Advanced pane, there should be a theme information link. Click that and it will show you the template filename suggestions for the different parts of the view. They're listed lowest to highest with the actively used one in bold.

Like in regular templates, create a file with the suggested file name, modify the suggested template, clear the cache, and view your... view.

Comment: Thank you. I sorted out by setting up the CSS classes to the fields and the I targeted them via CSS.  I am figuring out how to add some extra space between each view row (presented as a grid). Right now are very close. I have tried to add some space with css margin, but it does not help. Any idea?